# what is the meaning of keep it up in this situation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

my manager send me an email asking me to create two documents.

i create them in two days.

i send her these documents and she replied to me `Keep it up`

what did she mean?

```
does she imply that i should have done them faster?

does she imply that i have to keep awake for my mistakes?

or something else?
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think she meant "keep up the good work", which is a way to compliment you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Keep it up** is used to encourage someone to continue doing something:

> "You're doing very well everybody. Keep it up!"

Source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/keep-it-up